# on sort header column add and remove classes using vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a table and want to create a custom sort for the header using vue.

The header of the table look like this:

```
<tr>
    <th data-sort="name" class="sort">Product Name</th>
    <th class="">Url</th>
    <th data-sort="status" class="sort">Status</th>
    <th class="">Actions</th>
</tr>
```

the header is generated in vue:

```
<tr>
    <th v-for="data in headerData" :class="{ sort: data.sort }" :data-sort="data.sort ? data.sortLabel : false" @click="data.sort ? sortColumn($event) : null">{{ data.name }}</th>
</tr>
```

on click event:

```
 sortColumn(event) {
        let column = event.target;
        let data = column.getAttribute('data-sort');

        // change the clases 

        // send and get data from the server sorted
    }
```

**What I am interested is the frontend section (change the classes for the header)**

There are 3 classes: sort, sort-asc, sort-desc

EX when click on Product Name header:
1) on first click class sort must be replace with sort-asc
2) on second click class sort-asc must be replace with sort-desc
3) on third click class sort-desc must be replace with sort.

But in all this time when i click for example on Status header ... the other column headers must reset the class to sort (if there is another one active)

The search will function for only one column at a time.

Any ideas how can i do this using vue or vanilla javascript?

Answer (score 0):

This code do the job....I am sure there is a more elegant soclution .... but works :)

```
sortColumn(event) {
        let column = event.target;
        let data = column.getAttribute('data-sort');
        let activeSortClass = column.className;

        let sortColumns = document.querySelectorAll('#filterDataTable tr th[data-sort]');
        for (let i = 0; i < sortColumns.length; i++) {
            sortColumns[i].classList.remove('sort','sort-asc', 'sort-desc');
            sortColumns[i].classList.add('sort');
        }

        column.classList.remove('sort');

        if(activeSortClass === 'sort-asc') {
            column.classList.add('sort-desc');
        } else {
            column.classList.add('sort-asc');
        }

        console.log(data + ' ' + column.className);
    }
```